# In Ruby, what is are the specific methods to retrieve the return value of Class.new (an instance)?

Tags: ruby, class

Given the following code below:

```
class Animal 
end

dog = Animal.new # --> return value of Animal.new
```

What are the specific methods to retrieve the return value for Animal.new? I understand that a new instance is created from the class Animal and assigned to the variable dog. But what are the methods to retrieve the return value of Animal.new?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. Return value of `Animal.new` is __an instance__ of Animal.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: JFYI, return value of `Animal.new` (or any method) has no relation whatsoever with assignment operator. Assignment operator takes whatever value it is given and assigns it.

Comment: "updated the question" - still it's not clear. Do you or do you not know what class instances are?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion Sergio, my question did not correctly address what exactly I was looking for (really looking for what goes behind the scenes of Animal.new)... Have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Class.html#method-i-new):

> **new(args, ...) → obj**
>
> Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class’s* class, then invokes
>   that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*. This is the method
>   that ends up getting called whenever an object is constructed using
>   `.new`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for

Comment: I am not sure if it answers "what does the return value #<Class:0x007fe24193c918> mean or how should it be read?"

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali no but it does answer the OPs query. The question you are referring to was really an extra question I posted in the comments for another answer. I see you have posted an explanation for this in your answer below, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can test this yourself in `irb`. It returns an instance of that object.

```
# Instantiating a new instance of a class
irb(main):001:0> Class.new
=> #<Class:0x007fe24193c918>

# Assigning a new instance of a class to a variable
irb(main):005:0> some_var = Class.new
=> #<Class:0x007fe2410e68b8>
irb(main):006:0> some_var
=> #<Class:0x007fe2410e68b8>
```

Comment: what does the return value `#<Class:0x007fe24193c918>` mean or how should it be read?

Comment: that's just the object itself in memory. You really can't get much information out of it. However, if the instances of your class contain attributes—say, an animal breed—then when you instantiate a new instance of that class and pass in the animal breed, later when you call that object, it'll include the breed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A  
end
```

Calling `a = A.new` return the new object of class A, the string appear as eg `#<A:0x00000002d8eb98>` is the string containing human readable representation of the object from the default implementation of `inspect` method which is called each time new object is created.

The default inspect shows the object’s class name, an encoding of the object id and a list of the instance variables and their values User custom classes eg `A` should/adviced to override this method to provide better representation of their objects eg

```
class A
  def inspect
    "I am what i am"
  end
end

b = A.new
```

prints -> `I am what i am`not the hexadecimal value

Comment: No, it returns just an object. No strings.